# Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 with webkitEnterFullScreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, html5-video

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = 'video.mp4'
        var video = $(document.createElement('video'))

        video.attr("width", 300);
        video.attr("height", 150);
        video.attr("src", url);
        video.attr("controls", true);
        video.attr("id", "video");

        video[0].addEventListener("play", function() {  }, false);

        video[0].play();
        video[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();

        $('body').append(video);

    })
```

Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until the video's loadedmetadata event has been fired before calling webkitEnterFullScreen(). Please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226114/dom-exception-11-when-calling-webkitenterfullscreen) on stackoverflow or read [Apple's Safari docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html).

Answer (score 0):

this error means that the video is not loaded, make sure that path to the video file is correct and the video is loaded, and afterward you can try this:

```
if (document.mozFullscreen) {
    video.mozRequestFullScreen();
}

if (document.webkitIsFullscreen) {
    video.webkitEnterFullScreen();
}
```